# What is the best way to alternate between variables in a while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, variables, while-loop

What is the best way to alternate between two variables for different days of the week in a loop?

For example, let's say a person has planned strawberry picking and blueberry picking during the week, both of which have different procedures within the variables that need to be printed. If the person chooses to go picking for three days, then the order should follow: strawberry picking, blueberry picking, strawberry picking. If the answer is 7 days, then all 7 days should be printed as follows: strawberry picking, blueberry picking, strawberry picking, blueberry picking, strawberry picking, blueberry picking, strawberry picking.

So far, the only way I have figured out how to do this is to store the variables in an alternating list:
`fruit_picking = [strawberry picking, blueberry picking, strawberry picking, blueberry picking, strawberry picking, blueberry picking, strawberry picking]`

and then to index my loop as such:

```
i = 0
max_limit = days_picking
    while i < max_limit:
        fruit_picking_plan += f"\nDay {i+1}\n" 
        fruit_picking_plan += f"{fruit_picking[i]}"
        i += 1
```

Please let me know or give me suggestions! Not sure if this is considered hardcoding? No for loops please.

Comment: Perhaps check if i is even.

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a test on whether the day number was even or not to decide if it would be blueberry or strawberry picking:

```
i = 0
max_limit = 7
fruit_picking_plan = ''
while i < max_limit:
    fruit_picking_plan += f"\nDay {i+1}\n{'blueberry' if i % 2 else 'strawberry'} picking"
    i+= 1

print(fruit_picking_plan)
```

Output:

```
Day 1
strawberry picking
Day 2
blueberry picking
Day 3
strawberry picking
Day 4
blueberry picking
Day 5
strawberry picking
Day 6
blueberry picking
Day 7
strawberry picking
```

Note: to avoid an unnecessary `\n` at the beginning of the string, put all the plans into a list and then `join` that:

```
fruit_picking_plans = []
while i < max_limit:
    fruit_picking_plans.append(f"Day {i+1}\n{'blueberry' if i % 2 else 'strawberry'} picking")
    i+= 1

fruit_picking_plan = '\n'.join(fruit_picking_plans)
print(fruit_picking_plan)
```

Output:

```
Day 1
strawberry picking
Day 2
blueberry picking
Day 3
strawberry picking
Day 4
blueberry picking
Day 5
strawberry picking
Day 6
blueberry picking
Day 7
strawberry picking
```

Comment: @kamilla see my edit for a slightly better solution

Answer (score 0):

A bit overkill, but you could use a generator and `not` (or @Nick's method). And you could adapt this for more options without changing the main code which is nice.

```
def generate_fruit():
    opt = True
    while 1:
        if opt:
            yield 'strawberry'
        else:
            yield 'blueberry'
        opt = not opt
```

So if you do something like `print(list(generate_fruit()))` it will never end because `generate_fruit()` will produce fruit infinitely. But as long as you're going incrementally, it's fine.

```
max_limit = 7
print(
    "\n".join(
        f"Day {i}\n{fruit} picking"
        for i, fruit in zip(range(1, max_limit + 1), generate_fruit())
    )
)
```